# Pipeline with count and tfidf vectorizer produces TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, tf-idf, gridsearchcv

I have a corpus like the  following
'C C C 0 0 0 X 0 1 0 0 0 0', 'C C C 0 0 0 X 0 1 0 0 0 0', 'C C C 0 0 0 X 0 1 0 0 0 0', 'X X X', 'X X X', 'X X X',
I would like to use count and tfidf vectorizer along with logistic regression as a classifier.
The code below I have adapted from sklearn's samples.

```
from pprint import pprint
from time import time
import logging
import pickle

from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

print(__doc__)

# Display progress logs on stdout
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')


# #############################################################################
# Define a pipeline combining a text feature extractor with a simple
# classifier
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char',lowercase=False)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char',lowercase=False)),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression()),
])

# uncommenting more parameters will give better exploring power but will
# increase processing time in a combinatorial way
parameters = {
    'vect__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
    # 'vect__max_features': (None, 5000, 10000, 50000),
    'vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2)),  # unigrams or bigrams
    # 'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
    # 'tfidf__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'clf__max_iter': (1000,),
    'clf__C': (0.00001, 0.000001),
    'clf__penalty': ('l2', 'elasticnet'),
    # 'clf__max_iter': (10, 50, 80),
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # multiprocessing requires the fork to happen in a __main__ protected
    # block

    # find the best parameters for both the feature extraction and the
    # classifier
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
    corpus =['C C C 0 0 0 X 0 1 0 0 0 0', 'C C C 0 0 0 X 0 1 0 0 0 0', 'C C C 0 0 0 X 0 1 0 0 0 0', 'X X X', 'X X X',
             'X X X', 'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X',             
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 X', 
             'X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X 0',
             'X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X 0', 
             'X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X 0', 
             'X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X 0', 
             'X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X 0', 
             'X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X 0',
             'X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X 0', 
             'X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X 0', 
             'X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X 0', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X',
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X', 
             'C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C C X X X X 0 0 0 X 0 X X']    
    y_train = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    
    print(len(corpus),len(y_train))
    print("Performing grid search...")
    print("pipeline:", [name for name, _ in pipeline.steps])
    print("parameters:")
    pprint(parameters)
    t0 = time()
    #print(type(data.data),type(data.target))
    #print(data.data[:1])
    #print(data.data[:2])

    grid_search.fit(corpus,y_train)
    print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
    print()

    print("Best score: %0.3f" % grid_search.best_score_)
    print("Best parameters set:")
    best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
    for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
        print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```

My stack trace is as follows

```
Automatically created module for IPython interactive environment
50 50
Performing grid search...
pipeline: ['vect', 'tfidf', 'clf']
parameters:
{'clf__C': (1e-05, 1e-06),
 'clf__max_iter': (1000,),
 'clf__penalty': ('l2', 'elasticnet'),
 'vect__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
 'vect__ngram_range': ((1, 1), (1, 2))}
Fitting 5 folds for each of 24 candidates, totalling 120 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 4 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 120 out of 120 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-0d47590b1279> in <module>
    107     #print(data.data[:2])
    108 
--> 109     grid_search.fit(corpus,y_train)
    110     print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
    111     print()

E:\anaconda\envs\appliedaicourse\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    737             refit_start_time = time.time()
    738             if y is not None:
--> 739                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    740             else:
    741                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, **fit_params)

E:\anaconda\envs\appliedaicourse\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    348             This estimator
    349         """
--> 350         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    351         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    352                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

E:\anaconda\envs\appliedaicourse\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    313                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
    314                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 315                 **fit_params_steps[name])
    316             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    317             # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

E:\anaconda\envs\appliedaicourse\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    350 
    351     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 352         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

E:\anaconda\envs\appliedaicourse\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    726     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    727         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 728             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    729         else:
    730             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

E:\anaconda\envs\appliedaicourse\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1857         """
   1858         self._check_params()
-> 1859         X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
   1860         self._tfidf.fit(X)
   1861         # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so

E:\anaconda\envs\appliedaicourse\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1218 
   1219         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
-> 1220                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
   1221 
   1222         if self.binary:

E:\anaconda\envs\appliedaicourse\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
   1129         for doc in raw_documents:
   1130             feature_counter = {}
-> 1131             for feature in analyze(doc):
   1132                 try:
   1133                     feature_idx = vocabulary[feature]

E:\anaconda\envs\appliedaicourse\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _analyze(doc, analyzer, tokenizer, ngrams, preprocessor, decoder, stop_words)
    108                 doc = ngrams(doc, stop_words)
    109             else:
--> 110                 doc = ngrams(doc)
    111     return doc
    112 

E:\anaconda\envs\appliedaicourse\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _char_ngrams(self, text_document)
    255         """Tokenize text_document into a sequence of character n-grams"""
    256         # normalize white spaces
--> 257         text_document = self._white_spaces.sub(" ", text_document)
    258 
    259         text_len = len(text_document)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I ran the tfidf vectorizer alone and get the following results

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char',lowercase=False,ngram_range=(6, 6))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

print(X.shape)
print(X)
```

Results

```
<class 'list'>
[' 0 0 0', ' 0 0 X', ' 0 1 0', ' 0 X 0', ' 0 X X', ' 1 0 0', ' C 0 0', ' C C 0', ' C C C', ' C C X', ' C X X', ' X 0 0', ' X 0 1', ' X 0 X', ' X X 0', ' X X X', '0 0 0 ', '0 0 X ', '0 1 0 ', '0 X 0 ', '1 0 0 ', 'C 0 0 ', 'C C 0 ', 'C C C ', 'C C X ', 'C X X ', 'X 0 0 ', 'X 0 1 ', 'X 0 X ', 'X X 0 ', 'X X X ']
(50, 31)
  (0, 20)   0.31810783213188626
  (0, 5)    0.31810783213188626
  (0, 18)   0.31810783213188626
  (0, 2)    0.31810783213188626
  (0, 27)   0.31810783213188626
  (0, 12)   0.31810783213188626
  (0, 19)   0.16116825632411622
  (0, 3)    0.16116825632411622
  (0, 17)   0.16116825632411622
  (0, 1)    0.11378963445554637
  (0, 16)   0.22757926891109273
  (0, 0)    0.3413689033666391
  (0, 21)   0.17370780684495662
  (0, 6)    0.17370780684495662
  (0, 22)   0.17370780684495662
  (0, 7)    0.17370780684495662
  (0, 23)   0.11378963445554637
  (1, 20)   0.31810783213188626
  (1, 5)    0.31810783213188626
  (1, 18)   0.31810783213188626
...
...
...
  (49, 1)   0.01436413072356797
  (49, 16)  0.01436413072356797
  (49, 0)   0.01436413072356797
  (49, 23)  0.6894782747312626
```

**My Question**

Why is the standalone vectorizer working but when placed within pipeline that is used by Gridsearch  I get the Type Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, both CountVectorizer and TfidfVectorizer expect a sequence of items that can be of type string or byte. In your pipeline the CountVectorizer receives the corpus and outputs to TfidfVectorizer a sparse representation of the counts using scipy.sparse.csr_matrix. Since the input to TfidfVectorizer is not of the expected type you get the type error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object". Your pipeline works if you use either but not both vectorizers. For example,

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    #('vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer='char',lowercase=False)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='char',lowercase=False)),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
])

# uncommenting more parameters will give better exploring power but will
# increase processing time in a combinatorial way
parameters = {
    #'vect__max_df': (0.5, 0.75, 1.0),
    # 'vect__max_features': (None, 5000, 10000, 50000),
    #'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 1), (1, 2)],  # unigrams or bigrams
    'tfidf__use_idf': [True, False],
    'tfidf__norm': ['l1', 'l2'],
    'clf__max_iter': [1000],
    'clf__C': [0.00001, 0.000001],
    'clf__penalty': ['l2'],
    # 'clf__max_iter': (10, 50, 80),
}
```

produces the following output:

```
50 50
Performing grid search...
pipeline: ['tfidf', 'clf']
parameters:
{'clf__C': [1e-05, 1e-06],
 'clf__max_iter': [1000],
 'clf__penalty': ['l2'],
 'tfidf__norm': ['l1', 'l2'],
 'tfidf__use_idf': [True, False]}
Fitting 5 folds for each of 8 candidates, totalling 40 fits
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 4 concurrent workers.
done in 0.347s

Best score: 0.680
Best parameters set:
    clf__C: 1e-05
    clf__max_iter: 1000
    clf__penalty: 'l2'
    tfidf__norm: 'l1'
    tfidf__use_idf: True
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  40 out of  40 | elapsed:    0.2s finished
```